# Rivet bone over surface for Cloth rigging

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

I have found an interesting solution for rigging a cloth https://youtu.be/WOa0q8MZKyg?si=fNic7sMQgzryiOf3&t=247
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLak2NIwKqM

Is there something similar in blender that I can use to stick bones on the nurb surface or on the mesh? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmVj0luEDGw

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this for objects and bones.

For objects, you can attach the object to one vertex or three vertices (a triangle). The steps are as follows.

1. Select the cloth object.
2. Enter *Edit Mode*.
3. Select one vertex or three vertices based on which option you want to use.
4. In *Object Mode*, select the attachment then the cloth object.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select *Vertex* or *Vertex (Triangle)* based on your selection in step 2.

[image: Object]

Using one vertex is great if your object is on top of a vertex; however, if you object is on top of a face, using three vertices is probably better.

For bones, you can attach a bone to any number of vertices through a vertex group. The steps are as follows.

1. Select the cloth object.
2. Add a vertex group, and assign the vertices in *Edit Mode*.
3. Select the armature/skeleton.
4. Select the attachment bone in *Pose Mode*.
5. Add a *Child Of* bone constraint.
6. Set the *Target* to your cloth object and the *Vertex Group* to the vertex group you created in step 2.
7. You can optionally *Set Inverse* if you don't want the bone to snap to the selected vertex group.

[image: Bone]